# Avoid Visual Studio put tab/document open first

Tags: visual-studio, tabs

I am having an issue. Visual studio 2015 put the open window or tab always first, which is very annoying.

I want to open and don't change the tab position.

[image]

Example, if I open "PostFile.aspx.cs" keep it that position, and not go First, like ProcessSync is actually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Productivity Power Tools -> Custom Document Well

In the Sorting section, disable "Most recently used (disables By project and Alphabetically)".

Comment: Thanks for letting us know how to turn off that particular feature rather than recommending disabling the extension.  As a side note, is this really a "Productivity" increase having it sorted to be first? Seems like it just makes it the rest of your tabs move around, so it makes them more difficult to find, at least in my opinion.

Comment: Latest update to Powertools turns this off by default.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very bad behavior of the latest version of Productivity Power Tools for Visual Studio 2015. I have the same issue: I disabled this extension and now the tab working correctly.
Can you confirm that?

Comment: Is maybe a new option? Do you know if it can be deactivated?

Comment: No, I don't know. You can open Tools --> Options in VS and navigate to the section of Productivity Tools, but I can't see related to this new feature.